# Can i change the workflow's "To" section automatically?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I created a workflow to send email to the users. I made it in Sharepoint Designer. If any user's email address change, the workflow's TO section will change. How can i do this automatically?. Can i use a list to keep the mail address'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right lines. Create a list of user roles with associated e-mails. Something like;

[image]

Then in your To box select Workflow lookup for user...
[image]

In the next box choose the list with your Roles/Emails as the *Data Source* and set *Field From Source* to [Emails] and in the Find From List section set the *Field* to [Role] and the Value to the name of the role you want (e.g. Notify or Approver).

[image]

Now you can maintain a list of roles across your site and use them in your workflow without naming specific people inside the workflow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a great way. But i want to ask something. I do that like you say. but It is sending to only one mail address. I get this warning "the look-up that you defined is not guaranteed to return a single value. if more than one value is returned, only first value will be used." so, How can i achiieve that ? Please help me .

Comment: This refers to the match between Role and the text string you provide and not the returned Email string. If the Role is unique in your list all will be okay! You need to combine e-mails for multiple recipients using the ; as demonstrated in the example.

Comment: f_gulay if you are happy with the answer can you please mark answer as accepted - thanks

Comment: hahaha yess !! you saved my day !! Thank you .. you showed me the answer so clearly i am happy for this *-* Thank you thank you Thank yo ^-^. If i give you much more points , i want to give you again and again *-* That is not enough for me .

Comment: That solution is enough for me . but i just wondered , want to ask something more. Can i manage the permission levels from a list ?