# Workflows in SharePoint lists

Tags: list, workflow

I have a list already created for data incidents and I would like to add a workflow (to send an email to multiple staff) when a certain field/column (called 'personal data included') is set to a certain value.

E.g if 'personal data included' = yes, then send email to Joe blogs. If 'personal data included' = no, then send email to Mickey Mouse.

Thanks in advance
Donna

Comment: Have you downloaded Sharepoint Designer?  This would allow you to create a simple workflow, with some logic (IF field x = Yes -> send email to 'Group A').  You'll find plenty of existing questions on how to configure the workflow too.  I can post something if you need it.

Comment: If you are also wanting to manage the e-mails in a Group from a list rather than hard coding in SPD workflow you could make use of this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241545/can-i-change-the-workflows-to-section-automatically/241589?noredirect=1#comment257838_241589)

Comment: Hi, yes I have designer. Just struggling with the setting up of the workflow. Do i need to select 'workflow lookup for a user' or just type in the users name? If the former, then what options do I need to select? Many thanks

Comment: You have to select from 'workflow lookup for a user' or you get from SharePoint list item column.

Comment: Ok so under 'field data to retrieve' should data source = current item or current list? do I need to enter anything under 'find the list item' section? Thanks

Comment: You can find it under current item

Comment: Ah good, I see a few of us are helping.  I posted a [question and answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189787/send-alert-to-a-user-when-the-assigned-to-is-changed-in-a-list-item) on this myself a while back (lots of pictures too).  You'll likely find a few similar question on SP SE.